# Windows making call via bluetooth

Tags: android, windows, google-chrome, bluetooth

I wondering if someone could point me to the right direction where I can find the tools to develop a windows application that can do something of the following:

[image]

I want it to be able to make calls on the connected phone (Android) and use the pc's microphone and speakers to communicate.